# Injecting a genericized stub for testing purposes

Tags: java, unit-testing, generics, dependency-injection, hk2

I've currently got the following classes/interfaces laid out. The type `T` represents the format of data returned from `DataProvider` implementations. I'm using a factory so I don't need to attach type information to `MyStreamingOutput`.  I'm using `HK2` to inject the `DataProviderFactory` into `MyStreamingOutput`.

```
public interface DataProvider<T> {
    public T next() { ... }
    ...
}

public final class SQLDataProvider<T> {
    public SQLDataProvider(final String query, final RowMapper<T> rowMapper) { ... }
}

public interface DataProviderFactory {
    public <T> DataProvider<T> getDataProvider(final String query, final RowMapper<T> rowMapper);
    ...
}

public final class SQLDataProviderFactory {
    public <T> DataProvider<T> getDataProvider(final String query, final RowMapper<T> rowMapper) {
        return new SQLDataProvider<T>(query, rowMapper);
    }
}

public final class MyStreamingOutput implements StreamingOutput {
    public MyStreamingOutput(final DataProviderFactory dpFactory) { ... }
    @Override public void write(final OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException { ... }
}
```

This all works fine. Now I'm trying to set up a unit test for `MyStreamingOutput`, but I'm running into a couple of roadblocks. I wrote the following additional class for testing purposes:

```
public final class DataProviderFactoryStub implements DataProviderFactory {
    private final DataProvider dataProvider;

    public DataProviderFactoryStub() {
        this.dataProvider = new DataProviderStub();
    }

    public DataProviderFactoryStub(final DataProvider dataProvider) {
        this.dataProvider = dataProvider;
    }

    @Override
    public <T> DataProvider<T> getDataProvider(final String query, final RowMapper<T> rowMapper) {
        return this.dataProvider;
    }
}
```

The binding occurs in

```
final class QueryTestResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public QueryTestResourceConfig() {
        ...

        this.register(new AbstractBinder() {
            @Override
            protected void configure() {
                bind(DataProviderFactoryStub.class).to(DataProviderFactory.class);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

I can successfully inject this class into `MyStreamingOutput`, but it has a compiler warning because the typing information used by `getDataProvider()` isn't shared by the instance passed into the factory. I can't add type information to the `DataProviderFactoryStub` class because then it no longer implements the `DataProviderFactory` interface. I don't want type information on the interface because it's wrong - outside of the Stub case, the factories shouldn't care about the type returned by `DataProvider` instances. I'd very much like to avoid using setters for the `query` and `rowMapper` parameters because I consider it bad design in this case.

I can't shake the feeling that I'm either missing something subtle in my application of generics or something obvious in my application of dependency injection. What is the right way to address this use case? It seems like this is the kind of problem DI is meant to address, but I can't see how to fix it.

Comment: Why do you think adding type information to the `DataProviderFactoryStub` class would prevent it from implementing the `DataProviderFactory` interface? A templatized class can implement a non-templatized interface. (Maybe I'm misunderstanding you, though.)

Comment: Because I tried it. :-) If I template DataProviderFactoryStub, then that type conflicts with the type of getDataProvider(), because I specify it as public <T> DataProvider<T> .. That first <T> conflicts with the type of the Stub. Specifically: Type mismatch: cannot convert from com.locustec.eim.query.datasource.DataProvider<T> to com.locustec.eim.query.datasource.DataProvider<T>

Comment: Well, that's a good reason. :-) But I'm confused how this could be the case, though. If you define the class like this: `class DataProviderFactoryStub<T> implements DataProviderFactory`, and the method like this: `public DataProvider<T> getDataProvider` (and modify the constructor to take a `DataProvider<T>` instead of a `DataProvider`), shouldn't that work?

Comment: @Lilshieste That won't fly either. If you modify the interface method to be public DataProvider<T> getDataProvider(String query, RowMapper<T> rowMapper), then the compiler complains because 'T cannot be resolved to a type'. It needs to be either in the method definition or in the interface definition.

Comment: I would like to see how you bind these services into hk2

Comment: @jwells131313 added the binding code.

Comment: @jwells131313 ++ You got me halfway there, at least. I can inject a DataProviderFactoryStub instance instead of the class.

Comment: OK, so... then what is the second half of the question? lol

Comment: @jwells131313 The second half was how to fix the generics so I can get a DataProviderStub into the FactoryStub. I'm pretty sure now that the answer is "You can't", so I need to approach it a different way - probably by using a mock/stubbed ResultSet and a RowMapper implementation.

Comment: Sorry we couldn't help you get over that hurdle. Since the generic method determines the type used for `DataProvider`, and since any stub needs to be configured before that (unless it's hardcoded, as you mentioned), there's no way to assure the compiler/runtime that the types you specify are equivalent. As a result, it seems like the only other option left is to force the compiler to believe you (i.e., a type cast).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, due to type erasure, it isn't possible to do what I want. I will have to look at refactoring the existing code.

Answer (score 1):

When using DI, we usually end up with factory classes that are very basic (i.e., their creation methods are typically simple enough to fit on a single line). Your `SQLDataProviderFactory` class is a perfect example of this.

The reason for this is because a factory object is just a placeholder for the creation of an object. We want to avoid littering our code with `new` keywords, because doing so tightly couples code to a specific type. So we end up with factories whose methods are essentially just glorified `new` keywords.

I bring this up to point out that it's the type of the *product* that is important here; the factory is just a conduit. When you replace a factory with a test double, what you're really doing is replacing a product with a test double. This means that whenever I define a test double factory, I always have to define a test double product as well.

For example, your stub factory is just trying to return a stub product. The problem is that the *type* of the stub product it's returning does not match the type expected by calling code. If you define your own stub product, the code falls into place:

```
public final class DataProviderStub<T> implements DataProvider<T> {
    private final T dummy;
    public DataProviderStub() { }
    public T next() { return this.dummy; } // Just for example
}

public final class DataProviderFactoryStub implements DataProviderFactory {
    public DataProviderFactoryStub() { }

    @Override
    public <T> DataProvider<T> getDataProvider(final String query, final RowMapper<T> rowMapper) {
        return new DataProviderStub<T>();
    }
}
```

The stub factory only exists so you can inject the stub `DataProvider` into your SUT.

Comment: Hm. My issue is that the DataProviderStub passed into the DataProviderFactoryStub isn't recognized to have the same type as that returned from the get() method. The reason I'm passing the DataProviderStub in the constructor to the DataProviderFactoryStub is so that I can control the data on a per-test basis. I construct the DataProviderStub with a List<T> of data. If I understand it correctly, this solution requires that the data in the DataProviderStub be fixed for all tests. Am I misunderstanding your proposal? Is there a way to get per-test data into the DataProviderStub instance?

Comment: Oh, and thanks for all the thought you're putting into this, by the way. I appreciate it.

Comment: Dang, you're right. I'll have to think about this one some more. (Apologies for the side-tracking.)

Comment: What I could do is make the DataProvider in the Stub factory be static, and put a setter on the DataProviderStub. Then the test can at least have access to the values. It's ugly, but functional. Do you see a problem there? Or, of course, if anybody has anything better...

Comment: Except I can't make it static, because then there's no type information available and I'm back to square one. <sigh/>

Comment: I've been reminding myself of this a lot lately, so what's one more time: maybe the test is trying to tell us something. If we're having this much trouble trying to come up with a viable test double, other developers (or "future us") may have similar problems when trying to provide other implementations. So maybe the test is trying to [drive the design a certain direction](http://www.amazon.com/gp/aw/d/0321503627/).

Comment: I'm certainly amenable to changing the design .. I just don't see how I can meet my requirements (ability to stub out DataProvider with custom data, DataProvider must return type T, DataProvider ctor must take a String and a Rowmapper) with another design. If anybody has any thoughts, I'd be happy to try them.